# Variable is magically turning into undefined through stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Here are the relevant parts of my code. Notice the `console.log` statements.

```
async function matchChannel(
  context: coda.ExecutionContext,
  channelLabel: string
) {
  ...

  console.log(`allTeamIds = ${JSON.stringify(allTeamIds)}`);
  try {
    // promiseAny is a back-ported shim for Promise.any https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.any
    return await promiseAny(
      allTeamIds.map(async (teamId) => {
        // Get channels with either id or displayName as channelLabel
        console.log(`teamId = ${teamId}`);
        const channels = (await listChannels(context, teamId)).body.value;
        console.log(`teamId (after) = ${teamId}`);
        ...
      })
    );
  } catch (error: any) {
    ...
  }
}

export async function listChannels(
  context: coda.ExecutionContext,
  teamId: string,
  ids?: string[],
  displayNames?: string[]
) {
  console.log(`listChannels(teamId = ${teamId})`);
  return await tryDumpFetchParams<ListChannelsResponseBody>(context, {
    url: channelsUrl(teamId, ids, displayNames),
    method: Method.Get,
    headers: jsonApplicationHeader,
  });
}

export function channelsUrl(
  teamId: string,
  ids?: string[],
  displayNames?: string[]
) {
  function emptyArrayIfUndefined(arr?: Array<any>) {
    return arr ?? [];
  }

  console.log(`channelsUrl(teamId = ${teamId})`);
  ...
}
```

I'm getting the following:

```
allTeamIds = ["ee5e8e7a-ff63-4a6b-89e1-6b28be218ca3","1bd14e82-544f-4a4c-98c5-4c837596e8ae"]
teamId = ee5e8e7a-ff63-4a6b-89e1-6b28be218ca3
listChannels(teamId = ee5e8e7a-ff63-4a6b-89e1-6b28be218ca3)
channelsUrl(teamId = ee5e8e7a-ff63-4a6b-89e1-6b28be218ca3)
teamId = 1bd14e82-544f-4a4c-98c5-4c837596e8ae
listChannels(teamId = 1bd14e82-544f-4a4c-98c5-4c837596e8ae)
teamId (after) = 1bd14e82-544f-4a4c-98c5-4c837596e8ae
channelsUrl(teamId = undefined) <-- WTH
teamId (after) = ee5e8e7a-ff63-4a6b-89e1-6b28be218ca3
```

Why is `teamId` magically turning into `undefined`?! It's not like this is some closure that gets overwritten. Am I crazy or is this unexpected behavior?

Comment: I think you should check the data. It seems to be an array of objects. In the particular object, there might be some typo.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]? You're right that this shouldn't happen. However, it's not at all clear how it could happen. My best guess based on the code is that one of the items in `allTeamIds` is `undefined`. And the log you see is just off because of the asynchronicity - perhaps there is `teamId = undefined` log to match the  `channelsUrl(teamId = undefined) <-- WTH` log is way before this block of logs shown here.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Are you referring to `allTeamIds`? I printed it out. There are only two elements: `ee5e8e7a-ff63-4a6b-89e1-6b28be218ca3` and `1bd14e82-544f-4a4c-98c5-4c837596e8ae`. This is consistent with the other print messages. Notice how those are the only two id's that get printed. Otherwise, you'd see `undefined` in the other prints.

Comment: @VLAZ Ok, let me try to make such a MRE. However, like I told Approrva, the array has no undefined elements. The print is: `["ee5e8e7a-ff63-4a6b-89e1-6b28be218ca3","1bd14e82-544f-4a4c-98c5-4c837596e8ae"]`.

Comment: I should also note that I have the full list of logs for this execution. There is no matching `teamId = undefined` log to match the `WTH` log.

Comment: No repro ~ https://jsfiddle.net/f5pd8qcj/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was my mistake. Although I was getting an error, it was unrelated. I was actually returning successfully from `matchChannel`.

I'm pretty sure the `undefined` is due to a release of memory after the first promise resolved. It looks like the `promiseAny` was doing its job.

Edit:

Sorry for not seeing the comments earlier. I'll elaborate.

`promiseAny` is just going to evaluate to the first promise that resolves.

```
    return await promiseAny(
      allTeamIds.map(async (teamId) => {
        ...
      })
    );
```

When the successful promise resolves, the other promises aren't necessary anymore, so node is going to start cleaning up all of the memory involved in the other promises.

Note that `teamId` is an element in the array resulting from `allTeamIds.map(...)`. If I were to delete an element inside an array, I'd see undefined as well.

```js
const array = [1, 2];
delete array[0];
// prints 'undefined'
console.log(array[0]);
```

I guess this cleanup happens in a clumsy way where my print statements get executed after the memory cleanup. The event loop may just have kept on churning while the memory had already gotten cleaned up.

Unfortunately, my ability to reproduce was limited by the fact that I was uploading the code to remote servers with a custom sandboxed runtime.

Comment: @Clonkex this doesn't answer the question at all since a) the question is not reproducible, and b) there isn't any detail in this _answer_ that would help anyone else with a similar problem. The only thing this contains is some speculation about garbage collection

Comment: @Phil Perhaps, though it seems to me the answer is "the problem was unrelated to the question" and thus it's the correct answer.

Comment: @Clonkex I can't tell at all what this answer is even saying. Answers on StackOverflow should provide an answer for the question above. If the question is not answerable, it should be closed

Comment: Sorry for not checking on these comments. I elaborated the explanation. Hopefully that gives a lead to others. However, I don't have a path to reproduce.